# sliding logos - best way

Tags: javascript, performance, slider

I am creating event's page and at the bottom I placed many logos. It sliding from right to left. I don't use jQuery, only pure Javascript and I just wondering about the best performance. My code works, but maybe there is better way to do that ? I think this 'animation' sometimes slow down.

```
var banners = [],
    links = [];

links[0] = 'http://...',
banners[0] = 'img/logo1.png',
...

var banLenght = banners.length,
    banContent = "<div id='bannersBack'><div id='banners' style='display:inline-block;'>";

for (var ii =0; ii < banLenght; ii++){
    banContent += "<a target='_blank' href='"+links[ii]+"'><img src='"+banners[ii]+"'></a>";
}
banContent += "</div></div>";
document.getElementById('sliding-logos').innerHTML = banContent;

var actual = document.getElementById('banners');
var move = function(){
    position = actual.offsetLeft;
    position -= 1;
    actual.style.left = position +"px";

    // 3000 is sum of banner's width                
    if (position > -3000) { 
        setTimeout( move, 20);
    }else {
        actual.style.left = "0px";
        move();
    }
};
move();
```

Comment: Why don't you use jQuery?

Comment: This is tagged as JS, but the best performance way to do animations is probably CSS3 animations since it uses the GPU.

Comment: I don't use jQuery because I think it's stupid to load all jQ libraby to one animation. I don't need it anywhere else.

Comment: You could use one of these tiny scripts from [microjs.com](http://microjs.com/#animation).

Comment: Little fiddle with CSS, it should be improved: http://jsfiddle.net/tZ7Cy/

Comment: Ok, "I don't use jQuery, only pure Javascript" is the most important part of the post. I know there are thousands frameworks which do that for me, but I don't want it. I want know your opinion what's best performance in pure JS (or CSS3 like @Conqueror said)

Comment: CSS3, in my opinion, since almost all modern browsers have support for it, whereas if someone has JS turned off, they won't see your nice animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- single image  sprite rather than multiple image
- CSS Transitions rather than JS. CSS is part of the browser engine and doesn't have to modify the properties of the DOM so it should be faster

Here's an example (however it is does NOT work in all browsers yet)
http://css-tricks.com/infinite-all-css-scrolling-slideshow/

Comment: Javascript is not part of the browser engine? Is it a plugin? Umh

Answer (score 1):

Best performance is achieved by using CSS transforms+translate. Modern browsers will be able to use the GPU to do the transformation.

```
.animation {
    transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    transition-property: transform, width;
}
.move {
    width: 200px;  // set width to 200px
    translateX(-200px); // move 200px to the left (always relative)
}
```

Typically, if you move large images or large DOM Nodes, you will see some stuttering. With CSS transform you get *no* stuttering.

---

If you can't use CSS transform (because you need it to work in IE8 or lower) I'd use jQuery's `.animate`.

Comment: ok, I'll try your solution, but first I try figure out which class add where ;)